# How to describe Firebase storage security rules for several buckets in one file?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to describe storage security rules for several buckets in one `.rules` file. The bucket names are not known beforehand, however the prefixes of the domain-named buckets are known.

Suppose I have the following buckets:

- `uploads.<root-domain>`
- `original.<root-domain>`
- `edited.<root-domain>`
- etc.

I know that I can use [Deploy Targets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets) and put each rule into its own file, but I'd like to have all the rules in one file. Yes, I'm going to define a deploy target that will include all the buckets, and assign that target with my single `.rules` file.

I've tried the following approach.

```
service firebase.storage {

  // Original audio files
  match /b/original.{root}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }    
  }

  // Uploads
  match /b/uploads.{root}/o {
    match /{uploadCode}/{file=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But got error during deployment:

```
Error: Compilation errors in storage.rules:
[E] 4:22 - Unexpected 'rootdomain'.
[E] 4:9 - Missing 'match' keyword before path.
[E] 4:22 - Unexpected 'rootdomain'.
[E] 4:33 - Missing 'match' keyword before path.
[E] 5:5 - missing '}' at 'match'
[E] 11:3 - Unexpected 'match'.
```

So it seems that [wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#wildcard_matches) are allowed only for the whole path segment, not for a part of it.

Is there any way to have all the storage rules for various buckets in one file?